# How to change the Google Play email

Tags: google-play-store

I recently have gone from IPhone to Android. And my Google Play store is under an old email that has deleted its self. I have a purchased app that I need for school on this account, is there a way that I can change the email on my GooglePlay account without having to make a new account?

Answer (score 0):

Settings > account > google > *menu button > Add account.
Then go back to google accounts and delete the one you don't want.
This will change your play store email!.

*also, it may be slightly different on different roms. I gave you the most common method.